# Allow PHP Client URL Library to set cookies in my browser that are retrieved from a different site

Tags: php, curl, cookies

I visit A.com in my browser. A.com is a PHP page that makes a curl call using PHP's Client URL Library to B.com and it POSTs a username and password to it.

B.com returns a token to the curl call that A.com made to it.

A.com (the original page) then makes another curl call to C.com posting the token from B.com to it.

C.com then attempts to set a cookie in my browser that logs a user in.

When I visit C.com in my browser, I should already be logged in and able to browse the site.

My question is, can the response from C.com, even though it's responding to a curl call from A.com, set cookies in a user's browser.

Comment: You can retrieve server cookies with curl and serve cookies to the calling browser with setcookie or header. Di d you try that?

Comment: No, you can not set cookies for arbitrary domains. Your browser itself would have to make the request to `C.com`, for any cookie for that domain having a chance to get set.

Comment: @franzisk.  I've tried that and the browser complains about the domains being different.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Cbroe

Comment: Maybe I can get the token using PHP CURL Library, and then pass that token to Javascript, and let Javascript make the final call.